# spark job hang on the collecting when running on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I run a very simple application on AWS EMR, when I finished building the cluster, adding the step. I find that the application hangs on the collecting step.  Has anyone met the same issue?

from pyspark import SparkContext

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    sc = SparkContext(appName='Test')

    text_file = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
    counts = text_file.map(lambda word: word+1)
    print(counts.collect())
    sc.stop()
```

**The EMR shows:**

[image]

Why does it keep waiting at the collect step??

Comment: Use spark session, `spark` not context.

Comment: Can you check the yarn ui at <host>:8088 to see if you have enough resources?